# How to ignore several void method calls inside a void method in Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm testing a void method that happens to call several other void methods in a class (all of these methods are in the same class).  The method is something along these lines...

```
public void methodToTest() {
   methodA();
   methodB();
}

void methodA() {
   methodA1();
   methodA2();
   methodA3();
}
```

What I'd like to do is cause `methodA()` above to do nothing.  That is, I want `methodA()` to basically be like this:

```
void methodA() { }
```

I've tried both `doThrow()` and `doAnswer()` on `methodA()` to no avail.  It's as if those are both being completely ignored.

An example of what I've tried...

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockedClass).methodA();
```

Is there a way to do this just using Mockito?  I'm not at liberty to change the class that's being modified.

Comment: This should work, are you sure the `methodA` is not `final` ?

Comment: `methodA` is not `final`

Comment: looking back at  your snippet looks like you want to do a partial mock, maybe only executing `methodB`, while you are executing `methodA`. You are most certainly using `mock(YourObject.class)`, then of course a mock does nothing, and certainly will never execute real code. You can achieve what you want a `spy(YourObject.class)` it will execute the real code by default. However partial mocks is recognized as test smell, if not a design smell, you should look for opportunities to make the behavior of `methodA` as a dependency that you could expose in your API as a `AStrategy` for example.

Comment: maybe you understood the implication in the previous question, but the class itself cannot be final, or the method is final even if the modifier is not explicitly declared on the method.  So the class is not final either?

Comment: One point that has not been pointed out thus far is that in general it is not considered good practice to mock the class under test. If you need a test where the `methodA` has no side effect, mock the objects that `methodA` calls to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @KevinWelker - the class is not final as well

Comment: Just want to let everyone know that I have been reading your posts and I'm continuing to try and figure this out...once I get more light on where the issue is I'll update this post...thanks for your input

Comment: OK...think I might have found the issue...there's a call to a final method that's inherited from the class that my test class is extending.  So, am I right to assume that methods that call invoke final methods cannot be mocked?

Answer (score 32):

If you are looking to have methodB still execute, while methodA does nothing.  This will do that:

```
TestClass spy = spy(new TestClass());
doNothing().when(spy).methodA();
spy.methodToTest();
```

Comment: I didn't mention it above, but I actually am using a spy as you listed in your example.  I've attempted this exact code in my class and the internals of methodA() are still being executed which is what I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: are you using the inverted notation of `doNothing().when()` like above, or are you using the `when().thenReturn()` notation?  The latter form actually invokes the real method on a Spy when the `when` line of code is being invoked (i.e., when the alternate behavior of the partial mock is being altered), and that can cause problems.  Hence the need to use the former `doNothing` notation on spies to avoid that problem

Comment: @KevinWelker - I'm using `doNothing().when()`

Comment: I did a quick test before I wrote the post and it worked the way I described.  When does methodA get called?  On the doNothing() line or on the methodToTest line?  Are there any modifiers on the method signature on methodA?

Comment: For private methods check that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25020531/5151575)

Comment: I can confirm that the method still gets called.
doNothing() is actually meant for void methods, meaning that the method will definatley be called.

Answer (score 4):

```java
 @Mock
 ApplicationClass applicationClass; 


 Mockito.doNothing().when(applicationClass).myMethod(Matchers.any(Object.class));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It does not, @Ethan.

Comment: yes it does @f1v3

Answer (score 0):

Using a spy is only going to help you if you have a return type. You can use a mock of your class and doCallRealMethod to get the desired effect.

```
public void methodToTestTest() {
    MockedClass mockedClass = mock(MockedClass.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(mockedClass).methodToTest();

    mockedClass.methodToTest();

    verify(mockedClass).methodA();
    verify(mockedClass).methodB();
    verify(mockedClass, never()).methodA1();
    verify(mockedClass, never()).methodA2();
    verify(mockedClass, never()).methodA3();
}
```