# Mockito / Powermockito mock private void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I need to mock a private void method which takes no arguments using mockito and powermock.

The method belongs to a instance which is a spy.

I am aware the fact I need to do this suggests bad code but I am working with an old project converting the unit tests from one testing framework to another.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Thank You!

So far I have tried this:

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Whitebox.invokeMethod(spy,"method",null));
```

But I get this error:

```
No method found with name 'method' with parameter types: [ <none> ]
```

Comment: So far I have tried:

PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Whitebox.invokeMethod(spy,"method",null)); 

I get the follow error " No method found with name 'method' with parameter types: [ <none> ]

Comment: Ok, would be nice to have that in the original question though.. See my answer below, think it should work..

Comment: What happens when you remove the null parameter from the call to invokeMethod?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't tried Whitebox (which comes with Powermock), but try something like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod");
    }
    //Tests..
}
```

.. as far as I can remember..

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and I get this error: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!... the method is private void though...

Comment: Hmm, I think it must something that I can't see from what is provided. Make sure you have the method name right, and don't send null as a parameter..