# TooManyMethodsFoundException for inherited protected methods in PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Steps to re-produce,

1. Create a class with a protected method and override the same in subclass.
2. Create a test for the subclass and try to suppress the method call `throws TooManyMethodsFoundException`.

TestInterface.java

```
package com.test.powermock;

/**
 * Created by dineshkumar on 06/05/16.
 */
public interface TestInterface {
    public int testMethod() throws Exception;
}
```

AbstractTest.java

```
package com.test.powermock;

/**
 * Created by dineshkumar on 06/05/16.
 */
public abstract class AbstractTest implements TestInterface {

public int testMethod() throws Exception {
        return 0;
    }

    protected void voidMethodWithParams(String a) throws Exception{

    }
}
```

ImplClassTest.java

```
package com.test.powermock;

/**
 * Created by dineshkumar on 06/05/16.
 */
public class ImplClassTest extends AbstractTest {


    @Override
    public int testMethod() throws Exception {
        voidMethodWithParams("a");
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void voidMethodWithParams(String a) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("dd");
    }
}
```

ImplClassTestTest.java

```
package com.test.powermock;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by dineshkumar on 06/05/16.
 */
public class ImplClassTestTest {

    @org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void testTestMethod() throws Exception {
        ImplClassTest implClassTestSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new ImplClassTest());
        suppress(method(ImplClassTest.class, "voidMethodWithParams", String.class));
        int res = implClassTestSpy.testMethod();
        assertEquals(res, 2);
    }
}
```

After google, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/h1U5YyEXqfY

Also tried the following code,

```
package com.test.powermock;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by dineshkumar on 06/05/16.
 */
public class ImplClassTestTest {

    @org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void testTestMethod() throws Exception {
        ImplClassTest implClassTestSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new ImplClassTest());
        suppress(method(AbstractTest.class, "voidMethodWithParams", String.class));
        suppress(method(ImplClassTest.class, "voidMethodWithParams", String.class));
        int res = implClassTestSpy.testMethod();
        assertEquals(res, 2);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can suppress the methods ?

Comment: `implClassTestSpy` is a spied-on instance can't you just do a `doNothing().when(implClassTestSpy, "voidMethodWithParams", anyString())` or something like that? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020277/mockito-powermockito-mock-private-void-method

Comment: Yes, I can do that. What is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Redescribe the Question :

> use Powermock's `suppress + method()` cannot correctly get the `@Overriden protected` method : **voidMethodWithParams**, because the problem `TooManyMethodsFoundException`, find two methods which exist in class `ImplClassTest` and `AbstractTest`

**Problem** : find two method! Powermock didn't know to suppress which one.

```
    // encounter TooManyMethodsFoundException !!!
    suppress(method(AbstractTest.class, "voidMethodWithParams", String.class));
```

**Workaround**: This problem surely ugly, use java original way `foo.class.getMethod()`  **(just for public)** or `bar.class.getDeClaredMethod()` **(for Protected and Private)**

```
// "voidMethodWithParams" is protected method use getDeclaredMethod()
 suppress(ImplClassTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("voidMethodWithParams", String.class))
// "publicMethod" use getMethod()
 suppress(ContainPublicMethodClass.class.getMethod("publicMethod", foo.class))
```

**PS** : if you want to suppress all the method in one class, use powermock's `methodsDeclaredIn()`

```
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn;
suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(AbstractTest.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your mockito versions to the compatible mockito core mockito-all

Comment: You could give a little bit more of a detailed explanation here

Comment: this issue occurs when there are multiple methods with the same name and parameter types found in the class hierarchy. This can be challenging to deal with, especially when trying to mock or suppress methods during testing.